# Prove that $\frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{cd}{c+d} \leq \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$$\frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{cd}{c+d} \leq \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$$
I tried applying a.m. g.m inequality to l.h.s and tried to find upper bound for l.h.s and lower bound for r.h.s but i am not getting answer .

Answer (score 3):

Not a beautiful proof I have to admit, but it is a proof:

Multiply 2 sides of equation with $(a+b)(c+d)(a+b+c+d)$, we get to the equivalent form:
$$
ab(c+d)(a+b+c+d) + cd(a+b)(a+b+c+d) \leq (a+c)(b+d)(a+b)(c+d).
$$
Work out both sides of the equation above to reduce it to the following equivalent form:
$$
2abcd \leq a^2d^2 + b^2c^2,
$$
which is obviously true due to the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{cd}{c+d}=a+c+\left(\frac{ab}{a+b}-a\right)+\left(\frac{cd}{c+d}-c\right)=$$
$$=a+c-\left(\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{c^2}{c+d}\right)\leq a+c-\frac{(a+c)^2}{a+b+c+d}=\frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}.$$
Done!

Comment: I didn't understand the third step . Can u explain pls?

Comment: @swapnil v I used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the following form: $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}$ for positives $b_i$. In our case it's $\frac{a^2}{a+b}+\frac{c^2}{c+d}\geq\frac{(a+c)^2}{a+b+c+d}.$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $a,b,c,d$ are $>0$. An idea is to put
$$F(x)=\frac{(x+c)(b+d)}{x+b+c+d}-\frac{xb}{x+b}-\frac{cd}{c+d}$$
and to compute the derivative:
$$F^{\prime}(x)=\frac{(b+d)^2}{(x+b+c+d)^2}-\frac{b^2}{(x+b)^2}$$

This show that the minimum of $F$ on $]0,+\infty[$ is obtained for $x=bc/d$, and to finish you have to compute this minimum.

Comment: Can this be done using inequality